# python, pass a variable so it's recognized as an attribute

Tags: python, variables, object, attributes

how would i pass a variable, so it's recognized as an attribute? the exact error i'm getting is,

**AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'row'**

what i'm doing is writing data to google sheets using the gspread library

this code works,

```
wks = gc.open(row['sheet']).sheet1
```

but this code does not work,

```
wks = gc.open(row['sheet']).row['worksheet']
```

the difference is, there's no error if i hard code the worksheet value that i wish to write to **sheet1**, but if i pass **sheet1** as a value into the variable,  **row['worksheet']** then i get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me write your code as

```
temp = gc.open(row['sheet'])
wks = temp.row['worksheet']
```

I think there's no variable named row in temp, that's why you are getting attribute error. just to check whether row exists as attribute of temp, use dir(temp) or vars(temp).

Hope, It'll help you.

Comment: This is actually the correct way to do it